# Javascript from browser command bar open 2 windows (for Search engine customization)

Tags: javascript, search, browser

My idea is to create a custom search,e.g. dd, with javascript command to open 2 Urls , e.g. google.com/%s and bing.com/%s in 2 new tabs...

I couldn't make it work :(

tx!

following code in chrome console does not open 2 windows

> function myFunction() {
> window.open("http://www.ddd.com/",);  window.open("https://www.ccc.com/");
> myFunction();

I couldn't make it work :(

tx!

Comment: You forgot the closing curly brace "}" for your function before myFunction(); call

Answer (score 0):

You were missing a `}`

```js
function myFunction() {
  window.open("http://www.ddd.com/");
  window.open("https://www.ccc.com/");
}
myFunction();
```

[Disable your pop-up Blocker too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTnsU.png)

Comment: and coffee obviously :)

Comment: now launching this in chrome console only opens the first page, can u try too?tx !

Comment: Disable your popup blocker, see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTnsU.png

Comment: Chuck you have good eyes ! tx

Comment: So now, Let me try to get that working via a Search engine customization & report back